# Aligned Table of Notation Sybmols - Works but with Errors

Tags: tables, errors, columns

I am getting a four (4) errors and 1 Bad Box with the code below. However, the output is the way I need in the PDF.  Any ideas why I am getting the errors? And if so, how I can fix it.

The error is `Missing $` inserted in this code:

```
$y_{f}$ & $=$ & \left\{\begin{array}{rl}    1, &\mbox{ if Supplier located at site $f$ is open} \\0, &\mbox{ otherwise} \end{array} \right.\
```

---

```
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{table}[htbp]\caption{Table of Notation My Research}
\vspace{-1.5em}
\begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}{r c p{10cm} }
\toprule
$R_{i}$ & $\triangleq$ & Revenue at store $i$\\
$i$ & $\triangleq$ & index value for store locations\\
${T}_{c}$ & $\triangleq$ & A very long description of this specific variable and is needed in the research and looks good when wrapped and aligned to the left.\\
$TC$ & $\triangleq$ & Total overall cost(\$)\\  
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\underline{Decision Variables}}\\
$y_{f}$ & $=$ & \left\{\begin{array}{rl}    1, &\mbox{ if Supplier located at site $f$ is open} \\
0, &\mbox{ otherwise} \end{array} \right.\\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
    \label{tab:TableOfNotationForMyResearch}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you try to compile this MWE you should notice that you do not have more the `bad box`. In my solution I did not adopted the `mbox` to write the text and in the second example, instead of using the `array` environment I used `cases` (this allows you to see the difference).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\caption{Table of Notation My Research}
\begin{center}% used the environment to augment the vertical space
% between the caption and the table
\begin{tabular}{r c p{10cm} }
\toprule
$R_{i}$ & $\triangleq$ & Revenue at store $i$\\
$i$ & $\triangleq$ & index value for store locations\\
${T}_{c}$ & $\triangleq$ & A very long description of this specific variable and is needed in the research and looks good when wrapped and aligned to the left.\\
$TC$ & $\triangleq$ & Total overall cost(\$)\\  
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\underline{Decision Variables}}\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}\\
$y_f$ & $=$ & \(\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
1,  & \text{if Supplier located at site $f$ is open} \\
0,  & \text{otherwise} \end{array} \right.\)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:TableOfNotationForMyResearch}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This gives you as result:

[image]

If you want to have the caption much more near the table use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]\caption{Table of Notation My Research}
\centering % to have the caption near the table
\begin{tabular}{r c p{10cm} }
\toprule
$R_{i}$ & $\triangleq$ & Revenue at store $i$\\
$i$ & $\triangleq$ & index value for store locations\\
${T}_{c}$ & $\triangleq$ & A very long description of this specific variable and is needed in the research and looks good when wrapped and aligned to the left.\\
$TC$ & $\triangleq$ & Total overall cost(\$)\\  
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\underline{Decision Variables}}\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}\\
$y_f$ & $=$ & \(\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if Supplier located at site $f$ is open} \\
0,  & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}\)\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:TableOfNotationForMyResearch}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

that gives you:

[image]

Comment: yes. That resolves the question. I understand now now that the cases are a better approach than array for this layout.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you that you're using math constructs outside a math environment. In your case it's `\left\{ ... \right.` Wrap it with `$...$` or `\(...\)` and the error should go away:

```
$y_{f}$ & $=$ & $\left\{
  \begin{array}{rl}    
     1, &\mbox{ if Supplier located at site $f$ is open} \\
     0, &\mbox{ otherwise} 
  \end{array} \right.$\
```

Comment: that worked.how about the bad bod. Overfull \hbox 7.37781pt too wide)?

Comment: I can't reproduce the overfull boxes from your code excerpt. It would help if you could edit your question and provide a complete compilable LaTeX document that shows the issue.